# IText html to pdf not working in css of nested ol li list

Tags: spring-boot, itext

i have to create html from pdf with header html,footer html and water mark parts so i am using PdfWriter all css works except nested ol li

below is the code :

```
fileName = fileName.replace(" ", "_") + ".pdf";
String headerForFile = "", footerForFile = "", bodyForFile = "", waterMarkForFile = "";
//for document purpose
headerFromTop = headerFromTop * 96;
footerFromBottom = footerFromBottom * 96;
if (headerFromTop == 0) {
   headerFromTop = 0F;
}
if (footerFromBottom == 0) {
   footerFromBottom = 0F;
}
//document body code and pdfwriter code
Float defaultMarginTop = 36F;
Float defaultMarginBottom = 36F;
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(header)) {
   defaultMarginTop = 72F;
}
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(footer)) {
   defaultMarginBottom = 72F;
}
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, defaultMarginTop + headerFromTop, defaultMarginBottom + footerFromBottom);
byte[] finalPdf = null;
try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
   writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooterPageEvent(headerForFile, footerForFile, waterMarkForFile, headerFromTop, footerFromBottom));
   document.open();
   String cleanHtmlForBody = bodyForFile.replace("<br>", "<br/>");
   org.jsoup.nodes.Document documents = Jsoup.parse(cleanHtmlForBody);
   documents.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml); // Set to XML syntax
   documents.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml); // Use XHTML escaping
   String cleanedHtml = documents.outerHtml();
   try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(cleanedHtml.getBytes())) {
      final TagProcessorFactory tagProcessorFactory = Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
      tagProcessorFactory.removeProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG);
      tagProcessorFactory.addProcessor(new ImageTagProcessor(), HTML.Tag.IMG);
      final CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
      cssFiles.add(XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCSS());
      final StyleAttrCSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
      final HtmlPipelineContext hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider()));
      hpc.setAcceptUnknown(true).autoBookmark(true).setTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);
      final HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer));
      final Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
      final XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
      final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
      final XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, charset);
      xmlParser.parse(is, charset);
      document.close();
      //watermark placement and opacity code
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
      try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamStamper = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
         PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, byteArrayOutputStreamStamper);
         if (!waterMarkForFile.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            String filePath = "filePath";
            Image img = Image.getInstance(filePath);
            float w = img.getScaledWidth();
            float h = img.getScaledHeight();
            PdfContentByte over;
            Rectangle pagesize;
            float x, y;
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
               // get page size and position
               pagesize = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
               x = (pagesize.getLeft() + pagesize.getRight()) / 2;
               y = (pagesize.getTop() + pagesize.getBottom()) / 2;
               over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
               over.saveState();
               // set transparency
               PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
               state.setFillOpacity(0.2f);
               over.setGState(state);
               // add watermark text and image
               over.addImage(img, w, 0, 0, h, x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2));
               over.restoreState();
            }
         }
         stamper.close();
         finalPdf = byteArrayOutputStreamStamper.toByteArray();
      }
      reader.close();
      writer.close();
   }
}
document.close();
```

HeaderFooterPageEvent :

```
public class HeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

  protected ElementList headerElement;

  protected ElementList footerForElement;

  String headerForFile = "", footerForFile = "", waterMarkForFile = "";

  float headerFromTopForFile, footerFromBottomForFile;

  public HeaderFooterPageEvent(
    String header,
    String footer,
    String waterMark,
    float headerFromTop,
    float footerFromBottom
  ) throws IOException {
    headerForFile =
      "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"><tr><td>" +
      header +
      "</td></tr></table>";
    headerForFile = headerForFile.replace("  ", "&nbsp;");
    footerForFile =
      "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"><tr><td>" +
      footer +
      "</td></tr></table>";
    footerForFile = footerForFile.replace("  ", "&nbsp;");
    waterMarkForFile = waterMark;
    headerFromTopForFile = headerFromTop;
    footerFromBottomForFile = footerFromBottom;
    headerElement = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(headerForFile, null);
    footerForElement = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(footerForFile, null);
  }

  //used for header and footer
  @Override
  public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    try {
      ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
      ct.setSimpleColumn(
        new Rectangle(0, 832, 595, 782 - headerFromTopForFile)
      );
      for (Element e : headerElement) {
        ct.addElement(e);
      }
      ct.go();
      ct.setSimpleColumn(
        new Rectangle(0, 60 + footerFromBottomForFile, 595, 10)
      );
      for (Element e : footerForElement) {
        ct.addElement(e);
      }
      ct.go();
    } catch (DocumentException de) {
      throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
    }
  }
}
```

BODY HTML:

```
<html>
  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 11px;
    }
    ol {
      counter-reset: item;
    }
    ol li {
      display: block;
    }
    ol li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
    ol[style*="list-style-type: lower-alpha"] li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".", lower-alpha) ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
    ol[style*="list-style-type: lower-greek"] li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".", lower-greek) ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
    ol[style*="list-style-type: lower-roman"] li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".", lower-roman) ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
    ol[style*="list-style-type: upper-alpha"] li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".", upper-alpha) ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
    ol[style*="list-style-type: upper-roman"] li:before {
      content: counters(item, ".", upper-roman) ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>erfe</li>
      <li>frefef</li>
      <li>
        rfe
        <ol>
          <li>fcverf</li>
          <li>
            rfrefer
            <ol>
              <li>vdeerfeg</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything works as it should except ol li css in pdf i am getting this output:

> 1.erfe
> 2.frefef
> 3.rfe
> 1.fcverf
> 2.rfrefer
> 1.vdeerfeg

i have checked it with `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf();` and it works with this function but its not working with above mentioned code.